# Creating checkboxes dynamically from array VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, checkbox

I have a userform as following:

[image]

When I pick the database I want and click select, it gets me to the other page:

[image]

All those checkboxes are created depending on the output of an sql query.

In this example, the SQL query is:

```
ID            NAME
8             AI_EQ
14            BB_EQ
19            DM_EQ
22            GD_EQ
```

and so on...

I am adding the checkboxes in the select button as following (from a record set `rst`):

```
'creating checkboxes    
If Not rst.EOF And Not rst.BOF Then
       rst.MoveFirst
        i = 0
        Do
      With MultiPage1.Pages(1).Controls.Add("Forms.Checkbox.1", "Checkbox" & i)
.Top = yPos
.Left = 7
.Caption = rst![name]
.Width = 450
        .Height = 24
        .WordWrap = True
        .Value = False
        yPos = yPos + 17
  i = i + 1
      rst.MoveNext
End With          
            Loop Until rst.EOF
End If
 rst.Close
 cnn.Close  
Set rst = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing
```

Then, I would want the Finish button considering whatever checkboxes the user selects. For example, if he selects the first two, I would want to have "8,14" `ID`, so that I can add them into a new SQL query.

I guess I have to create an array to achieve this instead of just having `rst![name]`. But my attempts of creating it have failed, and even if I had the array correctly, I wouldn't know how to adapt it to have it return the `ID` when selecting the `NAME`.

This is how I am trying to create the array (but it is not returning anything)

```
 Dim MyArray() As Variant
For i = 0 To rst.RecordCount
MyArray = rst.GetRows(i)
rst.MoveNext
Next
```

Any hints/help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you are adding to an array, you would need to *Redim Preserve* the array and add to that, as you loop through items to be added to the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the checkboxes are created dynamically, do this.

1. Loop through all controls and check if they are checkbox or not
2. Check if they are checked
3. Check if they have something in `.Tag` and store it in a variable.

**Code**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim cCont As Control
    Dim cbString As String

    For Each cCont In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(cCont) = "CheckBox" Then
            If cCont.Value = True Then
                If cCont.Tag <> "" Then
                    If cbString = "" Then
                        cbString = cCont.Tag
                    Else
                        cbString = cbString & "," & cCont.Tag
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next cCont

    Debug.Print cbString
End Sub
```

But for this to work, when you are creating the checkbox, set the `.Tag` property to the `ID` value.

```
With MultiPage1.Pages(1).Controls.Add("Forms.Checkbox.1", "Checkbox" & i)
    '
    '~~> Rest of the code
    '
    .Tag = rst![ID]
    '
    '~~> Rest of the code
    '
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned Siddharth Rout:

```
  'creating checkboxes    

If Not rst.EOF And Not rst.BOF Then
    rst.MoveFirst
    i = 0
    Do
        With MultiPage1.Pages(1).Controls.Add("Forms.Checkbox.1", "Checkbox" & i)
            .Top = yPos
            .Left = 7
            .Caption = rst![name]
            .Width = 450
            .Height = 24
            .WordWrap = True
            .Value = False
            yPos = yPos + 17
            .Tag = rst![ID]
            i = i + 1
            rst.MoveNext
        End With
    Loop Until rst.EOF
End If
rst.Close
cnn.Close  
Set rst = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing
```